# Capture event over socket without knowing client

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I was wondering if it is possible to listen to socket events without having the exact socket. So rather than doing this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('event', function(data) {
        //code to be executed
    });
)};
```

I want to do this:

```
io.on('connection',function(socket) {
    //Do something on connection
});
io.socket.on('event', function(data) {
    //code to be executed
});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe there is some other way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this. Socket events are sent on the `socket`, and you need to listen for them on the socket.